# Math Equation Using % / Modulus / Remainder

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to figure out a math problem and I think the % is throwing me off. Have a look at this:

```
46 * 2 % 67 = 32
x  * y % z  = a
```

Now in this equation, how do I get x? When I have:

```
y = 2
z = 67
a = 32
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: what about this ? `var y = 2, z = 67, a = 32;x  = (a / (y % z));console.log(x);`

Comment: @HereticMonkey is this not programming because of the % from javascript?

Comment: @smart-googler That does not give x = 46...

Comment: You need the [modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of `y` in the remainder class field modulo `z`. This can be calculated relatively easily if `y` and `z` are coprime (especially if `z` is a prime) using the extended Euclidean algorithm. If they are not coprime, there might be no solution. Take a look at the Wikipedia article. This will probably give you more insight than the limited scope of a SO answer may give you.

Comment: It is not programming because it appears you're asking how to do algebraic math (solve for x). The fact that you've dressed it JavaScript clothing doesn't make it less about math. You could look at [math.se]'s [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to see if the question is on topic there (I don't know if it is).

Comment: Ok thanks Nico :)....and all good then Heretic, if this question needs to be closed that is fine with me

Comment: This looks like a programming question to me. Not so long ago, I wrote code in Python 3 to answer this very kind of question. That code is non-trivial, especially finding an answer when `y` and `z` are not relatively prime and to correctly show an error when there is no answer. Is that what you want (in javascript), Freddy Bonda?

Comment: @RoryDaulton I am not a mathematician haha, so you are going to have to post an answer for me to understand exactly what you are asking :) I don't know what 'relatively prime' means. I just need to find out how to get x haha

Comment: Note that your initial equation is off: `46 * 2 % 67` is actually equal to `25`, not `32`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code in Python 3 that does what you want, and raises an exception if no solution is possible. I use different variables names, but that should not be a problem. I don't know javascript so I'll leave the translation from Python to you.

Note that your initial equation is off: `46 * 2 % 67` is actually equal to `25`, not `32`. To solve the equation `x * 2 % 67 = 25`, call `divideresidues(25, 2, 67)` and you get the correct answer `46`. If you really want to find `x` for `y=2, z=67, a=32` then call `divideresidues(32, 2, 67)` and you get the correct answer `16`.

```
def divideresidues(dividend, divisor, modulus):
    """Divide the dividend by the divisor mod modulus. I.e., return the
    smallest positive integer solution to the equation
    x * divisor % modulus = dividend, assuming dividend and divisor
    are positive and less than modulus.
    """
    r, newr = modulus, divisor
    t, newt = 0, 1
    while newr != 0:
        quotient, remainder = divmod(r, newr)
        r, newr = newr, remainder
        t, newt = newt, t - quotient * newt
    if t < 0:
        t = t + modulus
    quotient, remainder = divmod(dividend, r)
    if remainder:
        raise ValueError('Bad division in divideresidues()')
    return t * quotient % modulus
```